# Varnish VCL in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, varnish, varnish-vcl

Is there any Eclipse plugin to do syntax highlighting and autocomplete for Varnish VCL?

I know that you can use vim and there is a [syntax file for VCL](http://cvs.pld-linux.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb.cgi/packages/vim-syntax-vcl/vcl.vim), so please do not recommend this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of 2014/03/06, there is no dedicated plugin for VCL.
Alternatively, you can get syntax highlighting with opening vcl file with "C/C++ Editor" included in Eclipse CDT (C/C++ Development Tooling) as vcl syntax is almost same as C language. There is no autocomplete with this method.

Instruction:
right click on default.vcl -> open with -> other -> (Check box on for Internal editors) -> C/C++ Editor -> push OK button.

CDT update site:
http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/kepler

Tip:
With [Remote System Explorer](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.rse.doc.user/gettingstarted/g_start.html) in [Eclipse TM (Target Management) Project](http://www.eclipse.org/tm/), you can edit/save default.vcl dynamically in the server. After you edit,save with C/C++ Editor, you can command "service varnish reload" in [Remote Shell View](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.rse.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftruncmdsview.html&cp=56_4_0).

TM update site: http://download.eclipse.org/tm/updates/3.5